# how to create relation between tree many to many table?

Tags: laravel

i have three table:

***Suppliers***

id | name

***Products***

id | name

***Attributes***

id | name

each supplier have many products and also each product belongs to many suppliers.
each product have many attributes and also each attribute belongs to many products.

my question is how to create relation between this tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would introduced two tables and adjust add product_id in attributes table  and store related ids in those tables.

**products_suppliers**

product_id - integer, 
supplier_id - integer

**supplier_attributes**

supplier_id - integer,
atrribute_id - integer

Comment: I don't think you understood my question correctly. there is no connection between suppliers and attributes table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understood my question correctly.
there is no connection between suppliers and attributes table.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to misunderstand.  But I think you can achieve it by introducing another take that has related tables primary Ids that links them